# parse image in dom parser using jsoup in android

Tags: java, android, dom, jsoup

i am trying to get the rss feed of this website:

http://www.phonearena.com/feed

here is my domparser activity:

```
public class DOMParser {
private RSSFeed _feed = new RSSFeed();

public RSSFeed parseXml(String xml) {

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(xml);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
        dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();


        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        NodeList itemChildren = null;
        Node currentItem = null;
        Node currentChild = null;
        int length = nl.getLength();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
             currentItem = nl.item(i);
            RSSItem _item = new RSSItem();

            NodeList nchild = currentItem.getChildNodes();
            int clength = nchild.getLength();


            for (int j = 0; j < clength; j++) {

                currentChild = nchild.item(j);
                String theString = null;
                String nodeName = currentChild.getNodeName();

                theString = nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

                if (theString != null) {
                    if ("title".equals(nodeName)) {

                        _item.setTitle(theString);
                    }

                    else if ("description".equals(nodeName)) {

                        _item.setDescription(theString);

                        // Parse the html description to get the image url
                        String html = theString;
                        org.jsoup.nodes.Document docHtml = Jsoup
                                .parse(html);
                        Elements imgEle = docHtml.select("img");
                        _item.setImage(imgEle.attr("src"));
                    }

                    else if ("pubDate".equals(nodeName)) {


                        String formatedDate = theString.replace(" +0000",
                                "");
                        _item.setDate(formatedDate);
                    }

                }
            }


            _feed.addItem(_item);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }


    return _feed;
}
}
```

everything is working fine except the image which i am trying to get through jsoup.

can anybody tell what i am doing wrong or missing?

Comment: How is the String `html`? can you post the String `html` of the line `String html = theString;` ?

Comment: Make sure your HTML string actually contains the image (img) you want.

Comment: thanks guys for helping me i will try what u are saying.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `theString` needs to be unescaped before passing it to Jsoup.

```
else if ("description".equals(nodeName)) {
    _item.setDescription(theString);

    // Unescape then Parse the html description to get the image url
    Element imgEle = Jsoup.parse( //
            Parser.unescapeEntities( //
                  Parser.xmlParser().parseInput(theString, "").outerHtml(), //
                  true //
            )) //
            .select("img").first();

    if (imgEle != null) {
        _item.setImage(imgEle.attr("src"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry Stephen for this late reply i was busy though.I tried your solution everything gets parsed except images do you have any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: *"everything gets parsed except images"* What do you mean?

Comment: I mean title,date is parsed and displaying but only image is not showing up.

Comment: How do you display title, date and image?

Comment: I used *DomParser* to get the data as i have mentioned above in the DomParser class and for images which are in *CDATA* Section in Description Tag i used third party library and *jsoup* library.Only title and date have been able to parsed and not the image which is the issue.

Comment: The code in my answer is supposed to give you the image url. You can't view (show) the image actually.

Comment: I'm not a Android developer so I won't be a useful helping hand here. However, you can search for "show image android example".